# How to pass command line arument in spring boot app when running from command line

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, command-line-arguments

I am trying to run spring boot app from command line and pass a commnd line argument. I tried several ways none of the works:-

```
Try 1: mvn spring-boot:run -DCALLBACK_PORT="8000"
Try 2: mvn spring-boot:run -D CALLBACK_PORT="8000"
Try 3: mvn spring-boot:run -DargLine="CALLBACK_PORT=8000"
Try 4: mvn -DargLine="CALLBACK_PORT=8000" spring-boot:run
```

In all case the app runs. I am trying to read it as:-

```
String evnCallBackPort = System.getenv("CALLBACK_PORT");
System.out.println("CALLBACK_PORT: "+evnCallBackPort);
```

It prints CALLBACK_PORT: null

How do I run it with this commandline argument?

Comment: Have you tried `System.getProperty()` instead? `-DCALLBACK_PORT=8000` does not mean that there is a system-wide environment variable called `CALLBACK_PORT` with a value of 8000. Relevant article: https://www.baeldung.com/java-system-get-property-vs-system-getenv

Comment: Has someone checked the documentation of the [spring-boot-maven-plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#goals-run) using `-DcommandlineArguments=..` furthermore why do you use a separate System.geenv part..you know the spring boot parts..like `server.port=8000` etc.?

Comment: If you really want load port via command line : mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--fCALLBACK_PORT=8080", see more https://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/command-line-arguments-spring-boot/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should add the following configuration into your pom file.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <environmentVariables>
                <CALLBACK_PORT>${env.callbackport}</CALLBACK_PORT>
                </environmentVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

In the pom file you define the environment variables of you application by environmentVariables parameter.ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#goals-run-parameters-details-arguments

Secondly, when you run your application, add the corresponding argument in your command line to fill in the placeholder in the pom file, in this example it is "${env.callbackport}" the correponding command line argument is -Denv.callbackport="3221" like the following command line:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Denv.callbackport="3221"
```

You can refer to the sample project https://github.com/bluezealot/mvnparam/tree/master/java2ets
The output of above command line is, note the output "CALLBACK_PORT: 3221":

```
$ mvn spring-boot:run -Denv.callbackport="3221"
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------< com.hoperun.java2ets:java2ets >--------------------
[INFO] Building java2ets 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.4:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ java2ets >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ java2ets ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ java2ets ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ java2ets ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ java2ets ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.4:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ java2ets <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.4:run (default-cli) @ java2ets ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []
20:57:14.223 [main] INFO com.hoperun.java2ets.java2ets.Java2etsApplication - args: 0
20:57:14.231 [main] INFO com.hoperun.java2ets.java2ets.Java2etsApplication - CALLBACK_PORT: 3221

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.4)

2022-04-20 20:57:14.702  INFO 99391 --- [           main] c.h.j.java2ets.Java2etsApplication       : Starting Java2etsApplication using Java 11.0.14.1 on qxz-ubuntu with PID 99391 (/home/qinxizhou/work/jtekt/mvnparam/java2ets/target/classes started by qinxizhou in /home/qinxizhou/work/jtekt/mvnparam/java2ets)
2022-04-20 20:57:14.703  INFO 99391 --- [           main] c.h.j.java2ets.Java2etsApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-04-20 20:57:14.917  INFO 99391 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2022-04-20 20:57:14.918  INFO 99391 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Redis repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-04-20 20:57:14.929  INFO 99391 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 3 ms. Found 0 Redis repository interfaces.
2022-04-20 20:57:15.212  INFO 99391 --- [           main] c.h.j.java2ets.Java2etsApplication       : Started Java2etsApplication in 0.913 seconds (JVM running for 1.135)
2022-04-20 20:57:15.213  INFO 99391 --- [           main] c.h.java2ets.java2ets.EntryService       : Console Start---
2022-04-20 20:57:15.214  INFO 99391 --- [           main] c.h.java2ets.java2ets.EntryService       : Console End---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.144 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-04-20T20:57:15+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I don't understnad what do u mean by "add the corresponding parameter to fill in the placeholder in the pom".  Without this, I tried and I get error as "[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase ".callbackport=3221". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal "

Comment: I added a sample project for reference, you can play with the project.https://github.com/bluezealot/mvnparam/tree/master/java2ets

Comment: Thx for your great afford. I can run the app. But when I tried install, it fails with msg: "There are test failures.

Please refer to C:\dev\github\mvnparam\java2ets\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream."

Then tired the same commadn `mvn spring-boot:run -Denv.callbackport="3221"` . It gives same errror: "[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase ".callbackport=3221". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal"

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know why you are continuously getting the error. I added my execute log into the answer. My JDK version is java-11, spring boot version is v2.6.4, if you have the same environment with me, the demo project should be able to run with command line:mvn spring-boot:run -Denv.callbackport="3221"

Comment: I am also using JDK 11. Btw, in the pom.xml there are many error like env.callbackport, app.argument cannot resolve symbol,  <folders>
      <folder> not allowed here

Comment: Sorry, I mixed the github project with my previous one in which used redis , in your environment the test case can't connect to redis thus you get the test error in mvn install, I reproduced the error on another PC. And deleted the useless reference of redis, you can now run mvn install , and you may try mvn spring-boot:run -Denv.callbackport="3221" again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244057/discussion-between-masi-boo-and-bluezealot).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking to pass **Properties** (instead of env vars), the syntax is slightly different ([source](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#run.examples.system-properties)):

```xml
<project>
    <build>
        <properties>
            <my.value>42</my.value>
        </properties>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <property1>test</property1>
                        <property2>${my.value}</property2>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Also, it is possible to do it via command line, which takes precedence over the configuration above:

```bash
$ mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Dproperty1=overridden"
```